# jszip in internet explorer is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to zip the selected files using `jszip.js`, which is working fine in both Chrome and Mozilla but not in Internet Explorer. Can someone help me in resolving this issue? I want a piece of code, which works in all three browsers.

I am using below piece of code for zipping and downloading

```
function Downloadzip{
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
    var content = zip.generate();
    location.href="data:application/zip;base64,"+content
}
```

since usage of `location.href`, its trying to redirecting to the page in IE.

Comment: Well, your Javascript's syntax is invalid, it won't run on any browser - not IE, not FF nor Chrome either.

Comment: can I know, whats wrong in the avove JS. Its working fine in both chrome and firefox. I am facing issue only with IE

Comment: That's impossible, it will not run on any browser as is. When creating a function, you need an argument list, even if it's empty.